Connection Sidekiq/Redis fail with code WSAENOPROTOOPT
I am building an Ruby on Rails app that rely on Sidekiq. This app run on a windows server VM and and Redis run on a Debian 11 VM.
When I am starting my Sidekiq server, I am met with this error message.
2024-05-17T14:54:24.857Z pid=27468 tid=jrw INFO: Booted Rails 7.1.3.2 application in development environment
Signal TTIN not supported
Signal TSTP not supported
2024-05-17T14:54:24.862Z pid=27468 tid=jrw INFO: Running in ruby 3.2.3 (2024-01-18 revision 52bb2ac0a6) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
2024-05-17T14:54:24.863Z pid=27468 tid=jrw INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2024-05-17T14:54:24.865Z pid=27468 tid=jrw INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: https://sidekiq.org
2024-05-17T14:54:24.866Z pid=27468 tid=jrw INFO: Sidekiq 7.2.2 connecting to Redis with options {:size=>10, :pool_name=>"internal", :url=>"redis://192.168.1.79:6379/0"}
Une option ou un niveau inconnu, non valide ou non pris en charge a ÚtÚ spÚcifiÚ dans un appel getsockopt ou setsockopt. - setsockopt(2) (redis://192.168.1.79:6379)
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:174:in `setsockopt'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:174:in `enable_socket_keep_alive'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:125:in `connect'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:51:in `initialize'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client.rb:746:in `new'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client.rb:746:in `block in connect'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client/middlewares.rb:12:in `connect'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client.rb:745:in `connect'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client.rb:732:in `raw_connection'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client.rb:697:in `ensure_connected'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client.rb:277:in `call'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/redis-client-0.21.1/lib/redis_client/decorator.rb:26:in `call'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:144:in `block in redis_info'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:163:in `block in redis'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in with'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:109:in `handle_interrupt'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:109:in `block in with'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:106:in `handle_interrupt'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:106:in `with'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:160:in `redis'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:143:in `redis_info'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.2/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:75:in `run'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.2/bin/sidekiq:31:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/sidekiq:25:in `load'
D:/Projects/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/sidekiq:25:in `<main>'

This message relating to the ERROR Code WSAENOPROTOOPT (10042) seems to indicate on error for the "optname" or "level" argument of the setsockopt function of the WinSock API.
However I have not find anyone having a similar problem with Sidekiq, so I suspect that the problem come from my end. But my conf file is almost empty (I can not see where the problem could be):
sidekiq.yaml

---
:concurrency: 10
test:
  :concurrency: 20
development:
  :concurrency: 10
:queues:
  -default
  -compute

I have followed the guide from the documentation  by creating a environment variable for the REDIS_URL.

Here seems to be issue in Network

Try ping 192.168.1.79 to check the host is reachable
Check Redis server is running on port 6379
Check the bind port of Redis server is not 127.0.0.1, it can be 0.0.0.0 in redis.conf
Try redis cli redis-cli -h your_redis_server -p 6379 ping

